# Encryption functions do not seem to be executing consistently during benchmarking; chrono records no time elapsed

Tags: c++, encryption, benchmarking, c++-chrono

So, I'm benchmarking my own implementations of the AES and 3DES ciphers and CBC and OFB modes of operation for a class project, using the std::chrono library. The basic setup is:

```
chrono::steady_clock::time_point t0 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
MODECALL_E (ptext, key);
chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
MODECALL_D (ptext, key);
chrono::steady_clock::time_point t2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
```

where MODECALL_E/D are macros that I change to whatever function I am benchmarking at compile time (specifically, the mode of operation function, which takes the cipher function as a template argument and then calls it internally). I then loop this code and record the times taken for encryption and decryption by a cast to chrono::microseconds:

```
timing_return ret;
ret.etime = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds> (t1 - t0);
ret.dtime = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds> (t2 - t1);
```

and then I store etime.count() and dtime.count() in an output file.

However, considerable numbers of runs for the AES cipher on both modes of operation are being recorded with zero time elapsed, sometimes for encryption and sometimes for decryption. I also tried casting to nanoseconds to make sure that it wasn't just a resolution issue, and there were still lots of zero entries, so clearly something is not functioning correctly. FYI, a typical time (varying for different key sizes) is in the 10-15 ms range for encrypting a 4 KB text file.

I ran the code in GDB and put an ignored breakpoint inside the called functions to count the number of hits, and...all the zero entries went away (and the functions were hit the correct number of times). This definitely seemed to be a result of the breakpoints, since I initially just set a breakpoint in the encryption function, and there were still zero entries for decryption, which then went away when I added a breakpoint to the decryption function. Unfortunately, GDB also adds noticeable overhead to the running time, so I can't just run the benchmark inside it.

I'm really stumped by this, does anyone have an idea what's going on? I compiled the code using -O3; could it be some optimization is skipping runs of the functions somehow? Note that this is only happening with the AES cipher, not 3DES, but it is happening with both CBC and OFB modes.

Complete code for the implementation (fairly extensive), including the benchmarking code, can be found at https://github.com/georgehodgkins/ECE5397project if there's anything else you'd like to see.

Comment: The steady-clock does not support nanoseconds on all systems. Use the [high_resolution_clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/) for timing functions.

Comment: If you are not actually using the results of your computations, I suspect the compiler is just optimizing them out entirely. Check the generated assembly.

Comment: The functions are not being optimized out; breakpoints placed in them get hit when the code is run (also verified via disassembly).

Comment: Depending on implementation, steady_clock() can have a resolution of e.g 10 ms ..  making it unreliable to measure in the 10-15 ms range .. Use high_resolution_clock() or measure several calls and calculate an average.

Comment: Changing to high_resolution_clock does not fix the problem.